# jQuery detect input fields are blank

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery how can check if all input fields (EXCL hidden fields) and textareas are blank? I'm not sure how to "loop" through all form fields and check for:

> $("input").val()
>   and
>   $("textarea).val()

This is to run a function that should only "work" if all form fields are blank.

Answer (score 5):

Take your pick, but here it is in just a few lines to validate all the fields, not just one:

```
var allBlank = true;
$('input, textarea').each(function() {
    return allBlank = allBlank && !$(this).val();
});
```

Naturally you can modify the selector to specify just the fields you want.  Then go on to:

```
if(allBlank) {
    //all are blank.  congrats. 
}
```

EDIT: Now with more performance!

Comment: +1 for the only answer here that is using boolean "flag", but it can be improved by breaking out of the loop when element with value is found - no point in iterating more elements.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Missed the "return".  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

go like this to `loop`:

```
$('input, textArea').each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val()) == ''){
        console.log(this,'is empty');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say extend jQuery to use the `:blank` pseudo class

taking an excerpt from the popular [jquery.validate.js](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js):

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.expr[":"], {
        // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/blank
        blank: function(a) {
            return !$.trim(a.value);
        },
    });
})(jQuery);
```

then you can use a selector like

```
$("input:blank")
```

---

if you're doing more than just checking blanks you may consider using the jQuery validation plugin

[bassistance.de » jQuery plugin: Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to achieve that.

```
$('#form-id input').blur(function()
{
if( !$(this).val() ) {
      // Do whatever you need to do
}
});

$("input, textarea").each(function() {
if($(this).val() === "")
  alert("Empty Fields!!");
});
```