# jQuery run function only if input fields are empty

Tags: jquery

I have a survey of which I want to record a user starting to complete it, by capturing the very first change in any input field or textarea.

So, if all fields (**except hidden fields**) are blank and any input / textarea change() is detected, I want to run the function rec_start.

> if( allBlank ) {   rec_start(); }

How can I detect allBlank? I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599504/jquery-detect-input-fields-are-blank) but added the hidden fields exception too late ... I'll accept answers in both question once I have a working solution.

Thanks

Comment: you can use it $("input[type='text']") to select only textboxes.

Comment: Don't need to select only textboxes. I need all input fields except hidden ones.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:not(:hidden)').......;
});

Answer (score 0):

You want to check for a change in a field e.g.

```
<script>
    $('input').change(function(){
        if( ($(this).val()=='' || $(this).val()=='the_default_value') && $(this).attr('type')!='hidden') { // might want to do the default value using $.data and looping through $(input) and storing their $(this).attr('value') in $.data
            //the field is empty react as you may
        }
    });
</script>
```